# How does db:schema:load affect future db:migrate actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

Let's say I've got an app with a bunch of migration files that I'm getting ready to deploy to production for the first time. From what I understand, I have essentially two options to get the db up on the production server:

- A - Run `db:migrate`, and have it cycle through all the migrations it hasn't yet run
- B - Run `db:schema:load`, and have it build the db from the schema file

I know B is the right choice for fresh deployments, as explained in the `schema.rb` comments:

```
# If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
```

What I'm wondering is, how does this affect migrations on the production server going forward? For example, if I do the following in order:

1. Run `db:schema:load` on new production server.
2. Change my schema in development and push to production.
3. Run `db:migrate` on production server

What will happen? Will it know to use only migrations that are more recent than the `db:schema:load` action, or will it try to run them all?

Comment: And you didn't think about simply running those couple commands to check yourself?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel - Who said I didn't think about it?

Comment: Your question suggests so. If you did you'd see it should work ok (as long as migrations db table is populated during `schema:load` which I didn't really ever check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The answer is that only migrations created after the latest `db:schema:load` event will ever be run.

The **schema.rb** file has a version stamp associated with it:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130928225041) do ...
```

When you run `db:schema:load`, Rails creates a fresh database according to that schema.rb file, and at the same time populates the `schema_migrations` table with all the migrations whose version number precede that of the schema.

So as far as I can tell Rails is essentially faking all the migrations up until that point, but doesn't actually run them. (I tested this out by generating an empty migration file, calling `db:migrate` locally, but then inserting an error into the migration file before deploying it to our server. On the server, we ran `db:schema:load`, and the result was that the bad migration was included in the schema_migrations table as if it had been run, even though it clearly had not.)