# rake db:schema:load not populating schema_migrations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, schema

I have a fresh database that I'm attempting to recreate, but running rake db:schema:load does not populate the schema_migrations table at all.  The result of this is every migration is now pending.  The schema version in schema.rb matches the latest migration, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072724/832777) would indicate what I thought was happening (Rails populates the migrations table with all migration numbers prior to the current migration nubmer) is, in this particular instance, not happening.  My coworkers have confirmed this is happening with their databases as well so it's definitely a project-wide problem.  We're using SQLServer with a custom schema, though the db user is correctly creating all tables.  I'm completely stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: John, your comment on the unaccepted answer was very helpful to me.  I think it'd be good to answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per D. Patrick, answering my own question:

So the end result was that another developer had installed `activerecord-nulldb-adapter`, which monkey patches `ActiveRecord::Schema.define` and doesn't run `initialize_schema_migrations_table()` or `assume_migrated_up_version()`. I uninstalled the gem, ran my `db:schema:load` just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run the command with the trace flag

> rake db:schema:load --trace

By the end of the log you should see lines

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0045s
```

Also, it worth to check does you test suit generate table from schema and the schema_migrations table correctly.

Comment: Weird, it does not.  In the dev environment these lines are the last produced:
`-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0034s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20131111151423, ["/Users/---/code/---/db/migrate"])`
   -> 2.1161s

The test environment does not execute those two statements.  I'm not really sure what would suppress them.

Comment: So the end result was that another developer had installed activerecord-nulldb-adapter, which monkey patches ActiveRecord::Schema.define and doesn't run initialize_schema_migrations_table() or assume_migrated_up_version().

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and Google brought me here. It's not the exact same problem as yours but I'll write this up in case it helps anyone who ends up here, as I couldn't find anything else.

In brief: `rails db:schema:load` wasn't setting my `schema_migrations` table correctly - when I ran `rails db:migrate:status`, the most recent migration was marked as `down`, even though it was clear from looking in the DB that the migration had actually been run. This meant that when I tried to do anything in my app I got an "migrations are still pending" error.

Turns out that the problem was `db/schema.rb`. At the top of the file,  the line `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180803094506) do` was incorrect. Thanks to a mix-up in my source control, `20180803094506` was the wrong timestamp. I fixed the problem by changing this timestamp to that of my most recent migration (i.e. the first part of the name of the last file in `db/migrate`.)

(The relevant bit of the Rails source code is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema.rb#L52) if anyone is interested.)